# How to compress before writing custom ETW logs?

Tags: compression, etw

We are logging custom events from application to ETW. Now need to find the best compression technique as lots of data will be written to the file and the etl file is to be send with error report to the server.

How to specify the details? In System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource itself, when setting it up?

Comment: use Keywords to only log important data ad skip other events if you don't want them

Comment: The purpose is to record all user actions, GDI usage during them etc. Later on a crash to use this info to reproduce the crash. Its a very huge application and having so much log info. Filtering aspect is another consideration. Compressing as well is required considering size of data.

Comment: ETW logging is not the best technology to record data on a very long run. The old data are unimportant for your purpose. Use circular buffer to override old data and at crash save the data which are in the buffer.